# Pass Travis-CI tests with Bintray deployment code

Tags: gradle, travis-ci, bintray

I have a library that I want to use Travis-CI on.

It is written in Java and uses Gradle as a build system and deploy to Bintray.

When Travis-CI runs the tests, it fails because I do not store my username and password in plaintext in the git repo.

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'project-name'.
Could not find property 'bintray_net_user' on com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayExtension_Decorated@18be0f81.
```

This is happening because I have not committed my gradle.properties.
How to I tell it not to run the deploy code, or otherwise fake it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're usually passing this property using -P commandLine option? The easiest fix for you might be to check if the property is available before you use it and initiate it with a sensible default if not:

```
if(!project.hasProperty('bintray_net_user')){
    project.ext.bintray_net_user = 'default'
}
```

Comment: This fixed the problem!  I now have green tests across the board.

Answer (score 1):

You can add user credentials stored to your `.travis.yml` [secure environment variables](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#Secure-environment-variables). 
Since you always have one of the two (local `gradle.properties`, or parsed `.travis.yml`), it will work correctly.